# How can I get the X and Y position of a path in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have some paths that are not inside any canvas, and I want to know how to get their X and Y position to create animations based on it.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="640" Height="480">
        <Image Source="SC.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="640" Height="480" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>

        <Path x:Name="but77" DataContext="77" MouseLeftButtonDown="MapClick" MouseEnter="MouseOver" MouseLeave="MouseOut" Fill="#FF2400FF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Height="17.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,104.875,68.125,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.875" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M555,105.375 L554.5,121.75 L571,121.875 L571.375,105.5 z" Opacity="0"/>
        <Path x:Name="but51" DataContext="51" MouseLeftButtonDown="MapClick" MouseEnter="MouseOver" MouseLeave="MouseOut" Fill="#FF2400FF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Height="17.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,164.125,70.375,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17.875" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M555,105.375 L554.5,121.75 L571,121.875 L571.375,105.5 z"/>
        <Path x:Name="but50" DataContext="50" MouseLeftButtonDown="MapClick" MouseEnter="MouseOver" MouseLeave="MouseOut" Fill="#FF2400FF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Height="17.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,70.375,178.375" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="17.875" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M555,105.375 L554.5,121.75 L571,121.875 L571.375,105.5 z"/>
        <Path x:Name="but82" DataContext="82" MouseLeftButtonDown="MapClick" MouseEnter="MouseOver" MouseLeave="MouseOut" Fill="#FF2400FF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Height="17.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,78.75,156.875" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="17.875" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M555,105.375 L554.5,121.75 L571,121.875 L571.375,105.5 z"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you need is the `TransformToVisual` method which is provided by all `UIElement` derivatives including `Path`.  To find the X,Y position of one of your paths relative to the containing `Grid` use:-

```
 GeneralTransform gt = but77.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
 Point but77Position = gt.Transform(new Point(0,0));
```